# MVC posting with a list of objects, collection is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am making a kind of walkthrough (step 1 > 2 > 3 etc) and one of the last steps is to select an item from a select list.

The view where the user selects from the select list has this model

```
public class EventAndCompany
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
}
```

And the view is

```
@model Prototypes.Models.EventAndCompany

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Step 3. Select questionnaire(s)</h2>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Step4", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EventID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CompanyID)
            <select name="Questionnaires">
                <option value="58926211-517E-4F5E-8E77-6256EC1832F6">Questionnaire 1</option>
                <option value="7477ECB1-C548-4532-9D07-C01DA50A5B2C">Questionnaire 2</option>
                <option value="EBE4D377-BF46-478B-AEF7-E8F853B8632C">Questionnaire 3</option>
                <option value="D94B7639-AF26-4CBE-A792-DCD7AC034BFB">Questionnaire 4</option>
                <option value="46544CFE-75A5-446B-8E6F-DB4E54B86890">Questionnaire 5</option>
            </select>
            <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" /></p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

And the action, they are submitting to, has this method signature

```
public ActionResult Step4(Models.EventCompanyQuestionnaires model)
```

And that model is

```
public class EventCompanyQuestionnaires
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public List<Questionnaire> Questionnaires { get; set; }
}
```

Questionnaire is

```
public class Questionnaire
{
    public Guid QuestionnaireID { get; set; }
}
```

When I submit the form to Step4 action, the Questionnaires model field is initialized, but the Count is 0 and the selected option in the select is not passed to the controller.

Comment: Why aren't you using a @Html.DropDownFor() when you are creating your view?

Comment: I am probably mistaken, but in the view which submits to step 4, it doesn't know about the object, so what would I add to the DropDownFor helper?

Comment: A select posts back a simple value (in your case a `Guid`). A `Guid` cannot be bound to a collection of complex objects. Its a bit unclear what your trying to achieve with this

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't know about the object?  How are you getting the questionnaire information to the view?

Comment: Right now it is handcoded as shown. I am trying to submit from ViewA to an action in a controller which requires a list of those Guids

Comment: Based on your view, your property in the view model needs to be `public Guid Questionnaires { get; set; }`

Comment: Or if you actually want to use a `<select multiple>` to select more that one, the the property will be `public IEnumerable<Guid> Questionnaires { get; set; }`

Comment: Exactly as @StephenMuecke says.  You would need the list if you were binding the select option list on the server side when you create the view.  Since you are just submitting a single item you just need to submit a Guid.

Comment: I'd also rename it Questionnaire or QuestionnaireId since you are only submitting a single value.

Comment: No, I need to submit 1 or many. If you see my class I have a Questionnaire class which is the singular QuestionnaireId

Comment: My best guess is that the property you have shown, you want for generating the options in the `<select>` (i.e. to replace you hard coded values), in which case you want a `public Guid SelectedQuestionnaire { get; set; }` property to bind to, and a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> QuestionnaireList` property for generating the `<select>` using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedQuestionnaire, Model.QuestionnaireList)`

Comment: then follow @StephenMuecke comment about submitting multiple ones.

Comment: Or `IEnumerable<Guid> SelectedQuestionnaires` and `ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedQuestionnaires, Model.QuestionnaireList)` if you want a listbox

Comment: And of course the view needs to be `@model EventCompanyQuestionnaires` (not `EventAndCompany`)

Answer (score 0):

just modify your post action to

```
public ActionResult Step4(Models.EventCompanyQuestionnaires model, Guid Questionnaires)
```